# CSS absolute element and calculate padding

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if this is possible with ONLY css.
I have a logo container that is positioned `absolute`. Since this logo can be **any** width and height it's positioned this way. Next to the logo div I have a navigation div. This element is positioned `relative`. Is there any way to keep the navigation exactly next to the logo div when that can have any width?

```
<div class="logo">
   <img src="logo.png" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
<div class="navigation">
   <ul>
     <li>....</li>
     // etc etc....
   </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
    min-height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 330px;
}
.nav-wrap {
    position:relative
    background: #ffffff;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

So what I tried is to use `calc()` but that doesn't work since you can't do something like(???)

```
calc(100% - (.logo))
```

I guess `display:table` won't work because there's an absolute element.
I can use jQuery but that would create a jumpy effect on the navigation.

So the question:
When a div can have any width and is p[ositioned absolute, how can you position an other div right next to it?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: No. An absolutely positioned element is removed from the flow of the page. Other elements will ignore it completely. Maybe if you described the reason you're using absolute/relative, we could give you another layout method that doesn't use absolute but pulls off the same UI.

Comment: Well, yes, kind of, with some limitations of course, where you need to nest the navigation within the logo div: https://jsfiddle.net/0nLtcvfc/ ... but as Michael wrote, let us know why you need the absolute element

Comment: That's not at all how [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) works.

Comment: @MichaelCoker: Ok the reason why it needs to be absolute is because it have to have the possibillity to overflow other elements. Since it's a theme I'm building there need to be endless possibillities of styling. Anyway thx for the heads up I think I have to re-think my approach ;)